# What is the best way to handle an analytical search on a large database?

Tags: search

I'm working on a web app which will allow the user to search a sports stats database for specific information they may be researching. Example - Player in the last five years who has had a double-double in five consecutive games OR Team which had 100 points in back-to-back games versus Montana State.

I'm trying to figure out the search interface for this type of search? Thinking I'd want to separate each portion of the query into a separate selection area... But not sure.

Comment: Player and Team are different entities, which have different attributes set. So you could implement separate consecutive searches for the entities, keeping previous result.

Comment: This covers a lot of different search parameter and search result possibilities. Is there a specific sport or sports that you are targeting here?

Comment: When the user enters the site they select which sport they are interested in viewing. The UI then is specific for that sport. For my prototype I'm starting with basketball but will then go to football and baseball.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are searching a database, users may be familiar with SQL vocabulary. You could introduce a graphical version of a command line SQL interface. 
Even if users have no previous database experience, applications like Axure and Excel often include GUI conditional logic elements. This level of detail is likely required for a system to return relevant results. It also allows users to easily see the full list of options available (e.g., players, teams, locations, &c).

[image: Excel' conditional formatting]